# How to get only the first matched value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

Edit: I meant to ask what is the best/fastest way to get the first match or the first xx matches.

I have an array

```
$arr = ('abc', 'ded', 'kjld', 'abr', 'cdfd');
```

I want to `shuffle` this array first, and then retrieve ONLY the first value that matches the pattern `/ab/`.  So, the returned value could be abc or abr.

I looked at `preg_grep`, but it will return an array of all the matches.  Of course I could just retrieve the first value of the resultant array, but that is wasteful and requires an extra step of array manipulation.  Is there another function or a `preg_grep` switch that specifies return only the first matched value (or first 5 matched values). I have looked at `preg_match` and `preg_search`, but they don't seem to give what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through your array and end the loop when you find a match using `break`:

```
foreach($arr as $value) {
    if(preg_match($pattern,$value)) {
        $return_string=$value;
        break;
    }
}
```

To specify a limit:

```
$limit=3;
$i=0 // sets the number of returned results to 0
$results=array();
foreach($arr as $value) {
    if(preg_match($pattern,$value)) {
        // add the result into the array and increment the counter
        array_push($results,$value);
        $i++;
    } if ($i=$limit) break;
}
```

You can then use another foreach loop to return your values like:

```
if(count($results)>0)
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result;
} else echo "No results found";
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, it works great to get the first match. Now I need to research how to get the first 3 matches.

Comment: You can also add a limit in the foreach by specifying a limit to a number you increment upon match, instead of breaking out of the loop. I will update my answer shortly to accommodate that

Comment: Thanks Ben for the help, I also did something similar to your limit approach, and tested the speed against the method of using preg_grep & array_slice to obtain only a array of certain size.  My original array to search has about 9000 values, so preg_match is faster if I only want the first value and the first value does not occur at the end of the array.  But preg_grep and slice is faster if more than 5 matches is needed. The orig intend was to find out whether there is a build-in array_slice option for the preg_grep method. Also in your code, use $result[]=$value is faster than array_push.

Answer (score 3):

Well I believe running `preg_grep` and then getting the first value would be fine, but alternatively you could loop your array and return when a match is found like this:

```
function firstMatch($arr,$pattern) {
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        if(preg_match($pattern,$item)) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return 'no match';
}
```

Comment: You're missing `shuffle`, but way to go :)

Comment: shuffle is not missing, that function work with or without a shuffled array.

Comment: What in case of `firstMatch(array('abc','def','no match'), '/match/')`?

Comment: @Tadeck obviously you could just change `return 'no match'` to `return false` if you wanted to. Depends on implementation really.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: I know that, but SO is full of people who would rather copy your code without modification. This is why I asked this question - for them to think a second before doing it exactly like they can see it within your answer.